# Why isn't the magnifying power in a compound microscope zero when image is formed at infinity?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, microscopy

1. I think, in a compound microscope, angular magnification and lateral(or linear) magnification is given by the same formula for both image at infinity and near point(D)
2. And the formula is $$M=m=m_om_e$$ (here $m_o$ and $m_e$ are lateral magnification by objective and eyepiece respectively).
3. Now when image is formed at infinity $$m_e =\frac{h_i}{h_o}=infinite$$
   So $$M=m=m_om_e=infinite$$
4. But I failed to understand why it is given by $$ M=\frac{v_oD}{u_of_e}$$

Comment: I suppose it's possible that the observer at infinity still sees the image as being larger than the object, which would constitute magnification exactly.

Comment: @Asher i am not saying there is no magnification . I wanted to say it should be rather infinite relative to D(near point) or focal length of eyepiece.